# What is the name of this PCB making software feature?

Tags: pcb, diptrace

While researching about PCB making I found exactly the feature I need, but forgot the name. It is the one which allows you to make PCBs with all copper and just thin lines, sort of inverted board style. It allows for strong currents to flow and would be ideal for the LM338K based power supply I'm building. It's a 5A 1.2 to 25V power supply, and I'm using DipTrace for the design.

This is a image to give you guys an idea, this feature has a name and I'm struggling to remember it.

Comment: Copper pour? That's not a Diptrace exclusive feature...

Comment: It can be called "plane layers", "split planes", "negative layers" or many other things.

Comment: yes, tried those terms in google, unfortunately, it was a scientific name based on some geometry theory or something, I was puzzled by the name so I tried it on google, and was surprised about the results. like saying lissajous figures, everybody can understand it, if in the trade.

Comment: in a single image, this is what I'm talking about. http://imgur.com/PaZyFX7

Comment: @ortegacomputacion  That's a "modernist painting" feature.  I'd be surprised if DipTrace supports that.  [Sorry, I couldn't resist.]

Comment: Looks like Voronoi filling to me, but that's probably not the actual name.

Comment: That's it!! Thanks Ignacio Vazquez Abrams!! Thank you very much! I was going to add even another image but no need now. you see Nick? modernist painting does have a name (lol)

Answer (score 1):

It is called VORONOI filling!! Thanks to [Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/11606/ignacio-vazquez-abrams) for the answer.

Comment: also called voronoi tessellation, a feature some pcb making software have, this is a great example, taken from another Stack Exchange question: http://imgur.com/4z4nrIy

Comment: hey Ignacio, if you post yours as an answer, I will surely upvote it as the correct answer, credit to you in my own answer might not be enough, I think. thank you very much.

Comment: https://groups.csail.mit.edu/drl/wiki/index.php?title=Visolate:_Voronoi_Toolpaths_for_PCB_Mechanical_Etch For one application...though concentrating on widening the actual high current traces is perhaps more sensible than widening all traces, especially when it comes to solderability/manufacturability.

Comment: With all due respect for Ignacio, I don't think that's an industry terminology.

Comment: @ortegacomputacion  The layout which you have linked in the first comment is not a Voronoi filling.  The copper pours and traces are drawn manually.

Comment: yes it is, perhaps not widespread, but he nailed it, its also called voronoi mapping, voronoi tessellation, check visolate, a software for pcb milling, lots of advantages, cleaner, not so toxic for the environment, and supports higher currents.

Answer (score 0):

DCB/DBC and MPCB/IMS are the most common PCB technologies for thermal/high power management.  See [Power Electronic Substrates on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_electronic_substrate)

Comment: yes, this is somehow related, but is not the answer I'm looking for, I'm looking for the name of a software feature so I can convert a low current capability board into a high current capacity board with just a couple of clicks after the pcb design has been made.

Comment: You can generate positive or negative artwork.  One shows where copper is (positive) while the other shows where copper is not.  Converting between the two is possible.